# Minimize mysql database hits from django query

Tags: django, mysql, django-templates, many-to-many

I am making a query in django that ends up hitting the database 4 times.  I want to be sure that there's no more efficient way of pulling the data than I already am doing.

I have a model:

```
class Film(models.Model):
   studio = models.ForeignKey(Studio)
   name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
   rating = models.ForeignKey(Rating)
   actor = models.ManyToManyField('Actor', blank=True, related_name='actor', db_table=u'moviedb_film_actor')
   staff = models.ManyToManyField(Staff, blank=True, through='Association')
```

My view is here:

```
def film_by_id(request, id):

   # Look up the car name (and raise a 404 if it can't be found).
   object = get_object_or_404(film.objects.select_related(), id__iexact=id)

   template_name = 'Film_by_id.html',

   association_objects = Association.objects.select_related(depth=1).filter(Q(film__name=object.name))
   source_objects = Source.objects.filter(film__name=object.name)

   object.association_objects = association_objects
   object.trim_objects = trim_objects

   return render_to_response(
        template_name,
        {"object" : object},
        context_instance = RequestContext(request))
```

And finally, my template:

```
Make: {{ object.studio }}<br>
Rating: {{ object.rating }}<br><br>

<u>--Actors--</u><br>
{% for actor in object.actor.all %}
    {{ actor.name }}<br>
{% endfor %}
<br>

<u>--Staff--</u><br>
{% for item in object.association_objects %}
    {{ item.staff.name }} - {{ item.get_type_display }}<br>
{% endfor %}

<u>--Source--</u><br>
<ul>
{% for item in object.source_objects %}
    <li>{{ item }}
{% endfor %}
</ul>
```

The debug toolbar indicates that I'm hitting the database 4 times.  The problem sees to be the ManytoMany fields and the "reverse select_related" I'm trying to execute with Source.

So the initial data pull hits once
Referencing Actor hits once
Referencing Association_objects hits once
Referencing Source hits once

So overall, is there a way to reduce the database hits?  Specifically, is there a better way to pull the many-to-many relations without creating more simultaneous database queries?

Answer (score 0):

You could eliminate the lookups for `Association` and `Source` if you were to use a `ForeignKey` relationship between them. Then `select_related` could pull these as well.

If you really, deeply care about optimizing the ManyToManyField I would suggest caching the result of the lookup.

Comment: ForeignKey won't work for Association because the nature of the data for this link is many-to-many, not many-to-one.  And for Source, I need the foreign key link on the side of Source, not film.  So it's like select_related, but as I understand it, you can't use select_related from the opposite side of the link.

Comment: Then caching is the way to go if this view becomes too much of a burden on the database.

Comment: Do you mean a cache per instance?  Or like memcache?  Could you edit your answer and add a little detail (maybe code) on that bit?  Much appreciated!

Comment: You could cache the results of the query, the view that uses the query, just bits of it, pretty much whatever you want, really: http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/cache/